# Repeat calculations over repeated blocks of 5 rows within numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array, of which this is a small sample. It repeats measurements 5 times, and I want to collate these blocks of five into a new array, where each block of five rows is now one row giving mean, median and standard deviation of the five initial rows

```
data = 
[[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.274035]
[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.269245]
[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.271161]
[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.269245]
[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.266370]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.085277]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.086235]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.090068]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.087193]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.085277]
```

What I would like to do is keep the value of the value in the block for the first 4 column, then find the mean, median and standard deviation of the next column, working iteratively over blocks of five rows.

```
data2 =
[[1, 9, 66, 74, mean[0:5,4], median[0:5,4], std[0:5,4]]
[2, 10, 65, 73, mean[5:10,4], median[5:10,4], std[5:10,4]]]
```

or in numerical terms:

```
[[1, 9, 66, 74, -0.270011, -0.269245, 0.002528]
[2, 10, 65, 73, 0.08681, 0.086235, 0.001777]]
```

I've tried this, but just get are zeroes as an output:

```
index.shape
Out[119]: (10,)

repeat = 5
a = 0
b = repeat
length = int((len(index) - repeat) / repeat)
meanVre = np.zeros(length)
for _ in range(length):
    np.append(meanVre, np.mean(data[a:b,5]))
    a = a+5
    b = b+5
```

(repeat is used as a variable rather than 5, as the amount of rows in the block is liable to change at a later date).

Any help you can give would be really appreciated.

Comment: So, every measurement has exactly the same number of entries?

Comment: Yes, that's right, each measurement has the same number of entries, which in this file is 5. Future files may be different, but this file they are all five

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def block_stats(data, blocksize = 5):
    inputs = data[::blocksize, :4]
    data_stat = data[:, 4].reshape(-1, blocksize)
    means = np.mean(data_stat, axis = 1, keepdims = 1)
    medians = np.median(data_stat, axis = 1, keepdims = 1)
    stds = np.std(data_stat, axis = 1, keepdims = 1)
    return np.vstack([inputs, means, medians, stds])
```